# Excel: Compare 2 tables and extract rows from both with a duplicate value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have two sheets listing out customer name, date, invoice number and comments in columns. The data in both of these sheets are different and in a different order. How would I cross reference column A(Name) in both tables and list rows from both sheets in a new table if the customer name is the same in both sheets?

Comment: you want you're answer with our without vba? also could you please make a small example, the generic description is a little hard to understand.

Comment: Without VBA would be best, but if it's the only solution I'd welcome it. Here's the example I'm working with.

Sheet 1 is pulling data into a table in this format:
https://imgur.com/KV6fT4H
Sheet 2 is pulling data into a table in this format:
https://imgur.com/ruFyzLE

I'm trying to create a table that will pull any duplicate names and their respective rows that looks like this (though, the format doesn't matter as long as data from both rows is shown):
https://imgur.com/7VbNAOt

Comment: Yes I think it should be possible using formulas, but it's not a simple solution, especially if a name is used multiple times one or both sheets. It will be much easier to implement it with VBA. Not sure anyone here has the time/motivation to solve it down for you. I would break down the problem and search for the solutions on the net. Maybe you go into a forum specialized on excel or pay a programmer if you don't want to learn it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll look into VBA. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything with a VLOOKUP or anything like that.

Comment: Are you looking to extract Duplicate row comparing bot Tables for Name? Could you share with us what did you applied to do so !!